# ¿Es correcto escribir "e" en vez de "he"?

Tags: ortografía, pretérito-perfecto

Al usar el préterito perfecto compuesto (*"Yo he conseguido"*), ¿es correcto poner "e" en vez de "he"? La frase sería *"Yo **e** conseguido"*.

Temo que sea correcto. Al hablarse, supestamente el "h" está omitido, pero quisiera pedirles la regla gramatical.

Comment: La hache no se pronuncia jamás en español.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero es clarificar que en español la *"h"* no se pronuncia.

En muchos casos es posible explicar que una palabra se escriba con *"h"* por razones etimilógicas:

- el verbo *"haber"* proviene del latín *"habere"*.
- el verbo *"hacer"* proviene del latín *"facere"*. La *"f"* en *"facere"* desaparece de la pronunciación, pero la ortografía converva la *"h"* como un vestigio de su origen.
- el nombre *"herejía"* proviene de griego "hairesis" (αἵρεσις).

Alternativamente, es posible consultar el [Diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/e) y confirmar que la Academia solamente reconoce la ortografía *"e"* en los siguientes casos:

- Sexta letra del abecedario español, y quinta del orden latino internacional, que representa un fonema vocálico medio y palatal.
- Signo de la proposición universal negativa.
- Símbolo del número trascendente 2,7183, que es la base de los logaritmos neperianos.
- Conjunción copulativa que sus sustituye a *"y" ante palabras que empiezan por i o hi, para evitar el hiato. Por ejemplo: *"Juan e Ignacio"*. *"Padre e hijo"*.

Answer (score 6):

No es correcto poner "e" en vez de "he". Ni con la primera persona del verbo, ni con ninguna otra.
La razón es que el pretérito perfecto se construye con el presente del verbo auxiliar *haber* (y el participio del verbo que denota la acción) y este, y todas sus conjugaciones, siempre deben ir con hache.

Answer (score 2):

Cabe que resaltar que hay que tener cuidado con este tipo de error. En países de habla hispana, el uso de las hache es algo que se adquiere con el alfabetismo básico. El equivocarse al no usar hache en el caso mencionado, y también con el verbo "hacer", es **uno de los errores ortográficos más graves que pueden cometerse** y la valoración del autor queda muy disminuida después de cometerlo.

Comment: Gracias! Ya pensaba que podría ser un error así.
Le he dado un correo formal a mi amigo peruano para que el pueda revisarlo. Al devolvérmelo, la ausencia del "h" me ha caido supechuoso. La información tuya me ayuda mucho. Gracias, edivimo

PS Tengo que acceptar la respuesta de Nico como respuesta preferida, por que él me dió la regla gramatical que había pedido en mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien explico lordDark , no es correcto ya que he viene del verbo haber. lo que puedo agregar que como mencionas en tu pregunta, la H en español es muda al hablarla lo que no implica que no tenga un significado gramatical , la letra E sola se utiliza comúnmente como conector entre 2 palabras y la segunda palabra empieza con la letra I por ejemplo : Comunico e invito a participar de un evento.